# getDisplayMetrics() returns incorrect density and screen size

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which uses a large-ish (1024x1024) bitmap. I've noticed that the performance drops significantly when it's being rendered, so I'd like to calculate the exact size of its ImageView in pixels such that the bitmap can be scaled once, instead of being scaled internally on every single frame (which is what I assume is currently happening - the profiler tells me that the internal draw() function alone takes up to ~30ms when the image is on-screen)

However, I'm not sure how to ensure that my image won't be scaled internally, since the display manager's resolution and density are COMPLETELY off.

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics() returns

```
density=3.00000, densityDpi=480, heightPixels=1920, scaledDensity=3.00000, widthPixels=1080, xdpi=442.451, ydpi=443.345
```

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics() returns

```
density=1.00000, densityDpi=160, heightPixels=526, scaledDensity=1.00000, widthPixels=320, xdpi=147.484, ydpi=147.782
```

While getResources().getDisplayMetrics() returns

```
density=1.00000, densityDpi=160, heightPixels=175, scaledDensity=1.00000, widthPixels=107, xdpi=147.484, ydpi=147.782
```

The issue is that all layout calculations (including px units) are based off the latter two, not the former. This is being run on my [Moto G5](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g5-8454.php).

I'm assuming there's something I'm missing in either my `AndroidManifest.xml` or `activity_main.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set an SDK version in `AndroidManifest.xml` directly inside the `manifest` section, eg.

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="15"
  android:targetSdkVersion="28"
/>
```

I figured it out when trying to get hardware acceleration working and I noticed that it was tied to the window manager.

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel):

> Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14, but can also be explicitly enabled.